# Failing to trigger checked event on checkboxes

Tags: asp.net

I have hierarchy which i need to bind to checkbox for parent and checkboxlist for 1 level children.

Somehow i cannot get to checkboxes(CheckBoxParent_CheckedChanged),checkboxlist's (CheckBoxListChildren_SelectedIndexChanged) select events, without UpdatePanel as well.

Working on it for 4 hours without any result, why i can't enter event when i check some checkbox ?

What am I doing wrong ?

Thanks

```
protected void Page_Load(object sender, EventArgs e)
{
    if (!IsPostBack)
    {
        ListViewCategories.DataSource = CategoryManager.ListHierarchy();
        ListViewCategories.DataBind();
    }
}

protected void CheckBoxParent_CheckedChanged(object sender, EventArgs e)
{
    if (((CheckBox)sender).Checked)
    {

    }
    else
    {
    }
}

protected void CheckBoxListChildren_SelectedIndexChanged(object sender, EventArgs e)
{
    if (((CheckBoxList)sender).SelectedItem != null)
    {

    }
    else
    {
    }
}




  <asp:UpdatePanel ID="UpdatePanelCategories" runat="server" ChildrenAsTriggers="true" UpdateMode="Conditional">
       <ContentTemplate>
            <asp:ListView ID="ListViewCategories" runat="server">
                <LayoutTemplate>
                    <div id="itemPlaceholder" runat="server"></div>
                </LayoutTemplate>
                <ItemTemplate>
                    <asp:CheckBox ID="CheckBoxParent" runat="server" Text='<%# Eval("Key.Name") %>' OnCheckedChanged="CheckBoxParent_CheckedChanged" /><br />
                    <asp:CheckBoxList ID="CheckBoxListChildren" runat="server" OnSelectedIndexChanged="CheckBoxListChildren_SelectedIndexChanged" RepeatDirection="Horizontal" DataSource='<%# DataBinder.Eval(Container.DataItem, "Value") %>' DataTextField="Name"></asp:CheckBoxList><br /><br />
                </ItemTemplate>
            </asp:ListView>
       </ContentTemplate>
   </asp:UpdatePanel>
```

Comment: Did you put the "AutoPostBack" of CheckBox to true?

Comment: omg, how did i missed that. thanks

Comment: @Hailton write your comment as an answer so that eugeneK can accept it as the answer. :)

Comment: Hanlet, thanks for reminding me.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Put the "AutoPostBack" of CheckBox to true.